# Android Gradle offline mode automatically enables after every build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I installed mapbox for android studio , and every since whenever I try to build the project, I get a message

- Disable offline mode and rerun the build

when I disable offline mode from the sidebar it still won't build, the only way to make it work is to actually click the 'Disable offline mode and rerun the build' link

it seems that after each build it defaults back to offline mode

is there a way to make it permanently enabled? cause right now I have to build the project two times every time I have to run it